How to dynamically change the report footer "Print At Bottom" settings depending on the number using Devexpress XtraReorts
XtraReport Designer
The above is the image for XTraReport Designer. There is a settings to toggle the footer to print at the bottom.
But the requirement here is to enable print at bottom if there is only one page. If there are more than one page, print at bottom setting for the report footer should be disabled.
I have tried it using the scripts tab. But I'm not getting the number of pages.
Script
Please give any solution for this problem
